# Using the MongoDB runCommand method in java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

How to use MongoDB runCommand method in java?
i'm using this `db.runCommand( { explain: { update: "info.asset", updates: [ { q: { "version": 3,"providerAssetId":"123" }, u: { $set: { "version": 9 } }, hint: { providerAssetId: 1, version: -1 } }] }, verbosity: "executionStats" })` in mongoDB console, But I want to use this command in Java, can any one suggest me how to use this in Java?

I'm using `mongo-java-driver-3.3.0.jar`

thank you

example :

```
DBObject explain = coll.find(condition).sort(order).limit(count).explain();
```

I can use explain for find method, but I don't know how to use explain on update method in java

Comment: You have to use db driver for query. What java db driver do use for this purpose?

Comment: i use mongo-java-driver-3.3.0.jar

DBObject explain = coll.find(condition).sort(order).limit(count).explain();

I can use explain for find, but I don't know how to use explain on update method in java

Comment: Do you want to call explain on update operation, am I right?

Comment: yes, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, explain is not supported anymore for most of methods. You can use fully the same RunCommand [method](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/current/usage-examples/command/) in java as in the shell

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have `MongoClient`, `MongoDatabase` and  `MongoCollection`:

```
MongoClient client = //here init connection
MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("DbNameHere");
MongoCollection collection = db.getCollection("CollectionNameHere");
```

you want to execute `db.runCommand(...)`
this command should be executed on db level (not on collection), it means you have to call smth like this:

```
...
MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("DbNameHere");
Document command = new Document("explain",
            new Document("update", "info.asset")
                .append("updates", List.of(
                        new Document("q", Filters.and(
                            Filters.eq("version", 3),
                            Filters.eq("providerAssetId", "123"))
                        )
                        .append("u", Updates.set("version", 9))
                        .append("hint", new Document("providerAssetId", 1)
                            .append("version", -1)
                        )
                    )
                )
                .append("verbosity", "executionStats")
        );
db.runCommand(command);
```